# c program works on windows take segmantation fault on linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, segmentation-fault

I wrote some c code on codeblocks. It works perfectly fine on Windows
but gave segmantation fault on Linux. Why ?

This is main. I used 3 libraries and opencells method calls a recursive method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
     srand(time(NULL));
    int size=atoi(argv[1]),trial=atoi(argv[2]);      //! program basladıgında gelen argumanlar
    int i,j;                 //! dongu degişkenleri
        int **matrix = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int));          //!matriksin 1 boyutunu dinamik olarak yarattık
        int *counters = (int *)malloc(trial * sizeof(int));         //! buda counterları tutcagımız array

            for (i=0; i<size; i++)
                matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int)); //! 2. boyutada yarattık

         for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            for(j=0;j<size;j++)  //! matrixsi sıfırla saçma sapan degerler geliyo yoksa
                matrix[i][j]=0;

            for(i=0;i<trial;i++)
            {
                   counters[i]=opencells(matrix,size); //!Random kapı açan ve bunun sayısını donduren fonksyon
            }
            printboard(matrix,size,trial,counters); //!Output.txtye yazdır
            for (i=0; i<size; i++)
                free(matrix[i]);  //! ramden aldıgımız yerleri sal gitsin
            free(matrix);          //! bosu bosuna makinayı zorlamayalım
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know where you get the segfault?

Comment: Create a core dump so that you can see what command results in the segfault. Without that this is a _guessing game_.

Comment: no ı run it on the commend line with gcc -o main.c main then ./main 10 100 it just says seg fault

Comment: Then compile it in debug mode and run with gdb. You should at the very least make an attempt to solve your problem before asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: Could your comments be fouling the compiler? They're non-english and Eclipse refused to let me even insert them as they aren't part of the Cp1252 character encoding. Its possible, that linux doesn't allow them whilst windows does.

Comment: ı used limit -c unlimited to see segfault it return 2 value nan and inf and i will try the commens out

Comment: Instead of using "sizeof(int)" when calculating the malloc size do it properly. You're allocating the wrong size for `matrix`.

Comment: @davidhood2: The matrix was created with a two-level `malloc`, so it should also be freed on two levels. Each `malloc` requires a matching `free`.

Comment: btw not the cooments i tried without the commends same mistake happened i think it supports UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int **matrix = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Change: (int) to (int*)

```
int **matrix = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
```

Because sizeof(int) and sizeof(int*) maybe different, so your program maybe crashed when access the not allocated memory.

Comment: Do not cast `void *` in C! C is not C++. And you did not really explain what OP did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
int **matrix = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Change: `(int)` to `(int*)`

```
int **matrix = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
```

And while freeing the memory then use

```
free(matrix[i]);
free(counters);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int **matrix = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

You are allocating the wrong amount of memory here. You want `sizeof(int*)` but you do `sizeof(int)`.

On windows, int and int* are both 32 bit big. On linux, this might well be different, and thus causing your program to incur a segmentation fault for accessing unallocated memory.